A. Zee's girlfriend visiting problem lead to symmetry-breaking
At the end of A. Zee's lecture https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9501022, he brings up a funny but seems unlikely story which puzzles me a lot, the original story and questions are as follows:

A physicist was lucky enough to have two girl friends, one named Lucy and one named Rita, whom he liked equally. The physicist lived on a train line precisely half-way between the homes of Lucy and Rita. (Thus, he found it convenient to think of everything happening in a (1+1) dimensional spacetime and of Lucy and Rita as the “left” and “right” excitation respectively.) Since he could never decide whom to visit, he simply left it up to chance. It so happened that on this line trains went left and go right at precisely the same frequency, once every hour. Our physicist thus went to the train station whenever the mood struck him and took the first train that came along. He figured that in the long run he would end up visiting Lucy just as often as Rita. In fact, after some months he found that he was visiting Rita nine times more often than Lucy! Unfortunately for our physicist, both women got angry at him, Lucy for his not visiting her often enough, and Rita for his hanging around her too often. He ended up with no girl friend.

What is the moral of the story?
How did it happen that parity was spontaneouly broken?
What does this story have to do with this lecture (and Wiegmann’s lecture)?


EDIT: I understand what happened in this story now, but I still don't know how it relates to spontaneous symmetry broken, especially with his lecture. If this is a poor example, can somebody explain why?

I doubt this is the original source, either, but Zee almost certainly got this from Martin Gardner's Aha! Gotcha:  Paradoxes to Puzzle and Delight (1976).  https://archive.org/details/ahagotchaparadox00gard/page/98/mode/2up

And if this is how seriously Zee took dating, I think my mother was right to turn him down when he asked her out.

Have you wondered why Zee ended his paper on this note instead of providing the answers?  Probably it's because he thought it would be more fun for readers to discover the answers on their own.

Consider trains coming at 06:00 and 06:06, and every hour later.

Thanks a lot @Ma Ye, so when the physicist waiting at train station, he has 9 times more possibility waiting the 6:00 one.

I got stuck at the "girl" part. Can you please define that symbol?

What is your physics question? You have posted no questions. All the questions I see are in the quotation. Are those your questions or his questions?

I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question about physics as a natural science.

In response to the edit: a classic example of spontaneous symmetry breaking (SSB) is a ball on top of a hill. Because gravity is pulling it down, it will roll down the hill to the bottom, but if the hill is rotationally symmetric then it has to "pick" a direction to roll down (that might happen because of a small gust of wind or something -- some small perturbation). So SSB involves an unstable symmetric situation, and moving to a stable state breaks the symmetry. Here, there's nothing unstable about the schedules being the same, so the fact that they are different is not really SSB.

@Andrew Thanks you, really appreciated!

Suppose that the trains going to Right depart every sharp hour: 9:00, 10:00, 11:00, etc., whereas the trains going to Left depart at 9:06, 10:06, 11:06, etc. If the times of leaving the house are drawn from the uniform distribution, the probability of getting to station in interval X:00-X:06 and taking the train to Left is 6/60=0.1.
This is a classical story in a probability/statistics class... but poor example of what spontaneous symmetry breaking is about, IMHO.

But exact train schedule is not mentioned in the task, and so it equally can be that train to the left departs at 9:30, 10:30,11:30 and in hence in this case probability to take train to the left is 30/60=0.5, i.e. equal distributions.

@AgniusVasiliauskas In fact, after some months he found that he was visiting Rita nine times more often than Lucy! The train schedule is the most glaring omission in the hero's assumptions. Of course, one could come with more ad-hominem reasons of why this happened - and they would be actually more consistent with what spontaneous symmetry breaking is about - fluctuations and errors beyond our control.

@AgniusVasiliauskas it  equally can be that train to the left departs at 9:30, 10:30,11:30 - not equally, but with probability of 1/60... unless we have other a priori information about the schedule.

I mean, that that your specific probability 0.1 is constructed just from one specific schedule example, which is a bit unfair (so I gave another schedule which gives another answer). Hence there must be a way to count probabilities over all time gaps between train departures and normalize them over getting to the train station times. I.e. just wanted to say that you draw over-general probability conclusion from too specific case (over-generalization argumentation reasoning error in your post).

+1. "poor example of what spontaneous symmetry breaking is about" -- totally agreed, there's no dynamics forcing the schedules to be different. Additionally, IMO Zee's framing of this story scenario is also in poor taste.

@AgniusVasiliauskas A Bayesian approach would be to treat the offset of the schedules as a parameter $\theta$, and compute the posterior $p(\theta|d)$, where $d$ is the data (ie, right is visited 9 times more often than the left). The likelihood would model the probability distribution of arrival times of the person at the station. I would expect the posterior to be peaked around 6 minutes, and the width of the posterior to decrease as the number of visits increases, so "in the long run" (as Zee says) I would expect this distribution to be sharply peaked around 6 minutes.

@AgniusVasiliauskas I gave specific time for simplicity - any 6-minute interval would suffice to produce 0.1. I think that, once the main idea is given, the OP can work out the details themselves.

@Andrew the framing certainly makes it a boys' joke, which was probably ok when Zee was a young man, but poor taste by modern standards. When I heard it for the first time, it was firmulated in more neutral terms - a person taking a train to work, which train they take more frequently. Trains could have alternating colors or something like that.

I wanted to write a funny answer, however, my conclusion was wrong and it did not deliver the desired punchline.
As for your edit: The reason this is a poor example is because there is nothing spontaneous about this symmetry breaking. The hidden assumption in when the guy actually visits someone more is the time the trains depart. Assuming Lucy's departs at sharp, the threshold minute at which Rita's departs is determining whether he visits who more often. In fact, in a completely symmetric scenario (that is, when the symmetry is fundamental), the trains leave with equal time distance, i.e. at sharp and half past respectively and he visits both people equally often.
Zee's example is one for explicit symmetry breaking - Rita and Lucy never had the same chances to begin with!
Comments and Roger's answer have already calculated why this is the case.
